# next-themes - When default is dark there is a frame background come as light theme

Tags: next.js13, nextui

I use next-js 13 and tailwind
i have a layout with vanta js. (https://www.vantajs.com/?effect=waves) My default theme is dark. I use this as a background on my pages. Below code everything works fine with small bug. When i refresh the page i can see first load bg-gray-600 background (which is light theme background) then wave and then theme changes and it display dark:bg-gray-800 (which is dark theme background) . How can i get rid of this effect?

```
`export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang='en' suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
      <link rel='icon' href='/Favicon.ico' sizes='any' />
      <body className={inter.className + 'relative bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-800'}>
        <div className='fixed left-0 top-0 -z-10 h-full w-full opacity-40'>
          <VantaWaves />
        </div>
        <ThemeProviderx>
          <div className='z-10 min-h-[100vh]'>{children}</div>
        </ThemeProviderx>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}`

'use client';
import { ThemeProvider, useTheme } from 'next-themes';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { Tooltip as ReactTooltip } from 'react-tooltip';

export const ThemeProviderx = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);
  if (!mounted) return null;
  return (
    <ThemeProvider attribute='class' defaultTheme='dark'>
      <Toaster />
      <ReactTooltip id='my-tooltip' className='z-50' afterShow={() => {}} />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export const ThemeButton = () => {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

  const handleTheme = () => {
    if (theme == 'dark') {
      setTheme('light');
    } else {
      setTheme('dark');
    }
  };
  return (
    <button
      onClick={handleTheme}
      className='js-dark-mode-trigger group flex h-10 w-10 items-center justify-center rounded-full border border-black bg-white transition-colors dark:border-transparent dark:bg-white/[.15]'
    ></button>
  );
};
```